# How to update an array object in Dynamodb Golang

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

Tried below code , but not able to update array of string in dynamodb
info := []{"one","two"}

```
let params = {
  TableName: room-table,
  Key: {
    uuid: event.body.uuid
  },
  UpdateExpression : "??",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "??":"??"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    "values":types.AttributeValueMemberL{value: info},
  },
  ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW"
};
```

It will save in dynamodb as

"value": ["one", "two"]

```
    val:=[]{"one","two"}
    out, errs := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("Table1"),
        Key: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "PK": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: pk},
            "SK": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: pk},
        },
        UpdateExpression: aws.String("set info = :info"),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            ":info": types.AttributeValueMemberL{value:val},
        },
        ReturnValues: types.ReturnValueUpdatedNew,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a small example of how to deal with DynamoDb.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"
)

func main() {
    cfg, _ := GetAwsConfig()
    dynaClient := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(*cfg)

    // create table
    dynaClient.CreateTable(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.CreateTableInput{
        TableName: aws.String("colors"),
        AttributeDefinitions: []types.AttributeDefinition{
            {
                AttributeName: aws.String("user"),
                AttributeType: types.ScalarAttributeTypeS,
            },
        },
        KeySchema: []types.KeySchemaElement{
            {
                AttributeName: aws.String("user"),
                KeyType:       types.KeyTypeHash,
            },
        },
        BillingMode: types.BillingModePayPerRequest,
    })

    defer func() {
        dynaClient.DeleteTable(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.DeleteTableInput{
            TableName: aws.String("colors"),
        })
    }()

    // load table
    dynaClient.PutItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("colors"),
        Item: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "user":   &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "user1"},
            "colors": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: `["red","green","blue"]`},
        },
    })

    // read colors
    var colors []string
    var colorString string
    res, _ := dynaClient.GetItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("colors"),
        Key: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "user": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "user1"},
        },
    })

    attributevalue.Unmarshal(res.Item["colors"], &colorString)

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(colorString), &colors)

    for k, v := range colors {
        fmt.Printf("k: %d\tv: %q\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

The relevant part for your question is the one delimited by the commend `// load table`. Here, you can see how to upload data to DynamoDb.
As you question is a little generic, let me know if this helps you or you need something more accurate!

Comment: I have updated my code , but it is not working

Comment: What error do you have? Maybe update the code in the question with everything, not only the relevant code so I'll be able to repro your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ParwinderKumar, do you have any news?

Comment: I found a solution as per my requirement , I ll share it here